# Undefined variable: total in

Tags: php

I am using foreach over an array and adding each member and assigning total to a variable.

It works like i want, but I get the error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: total in C:\xampp\htdocs\preg.php on line
>   10

I dont quite understand how/why this works and why I get the ^^ error

```
<?php
    $bar = [1,2,3,5,36];
    foreach($bar as $value) {
        $total = ($total += $value);        
    }

    echo $total;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the `foreach` you need

```
$total = 0;
foreach($bar as $value){....
```

The `$total` variable wasn't initialised, so it couldn't be added to itself. Also, you can rewrite the whole thing like this:

```
$bar = [1,2,3,4,5];
$total = 0;
foreach($var as $value) {
    $total += $value;
}
echo $total;
```